# Matched elements using regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a hash which contains a regular expression: the number of matches to be captured in it and variables and their position of match. For example:

```
my %hash = (
    reg_ex => 'Variable1:\s+(.*?)\s+\n\s+Variable2:\s+(.*?)\s+\n',
    count => 2,
    Variable1 => 1,
    Variable2  => 2,
);
```

I am going to use this regex in some other part of code where I will be just giving say `$to_be_matched_variable =~ /$hash{reg_ex}/` and we obtain the required matches here in `$1`, `$2`, ...

I need to use the value of the key `Variable1`, which indicates the number of the match to be used in place where we normally use `$1`.

I tried giving `$.$hash{Variable1}` and `$,$hash{Variable1}`. I am not able to find how to frame something that will be equivalent to `$1`, `$2`...

Comment: This smells like something else is wrong with your architecture. What task are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'd suggest having reg_ex => qr/.../, so the whole thing is a bit clearer (IMO)

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
(my @ArrayOfMatches) = $to_be_matched_variable =~ /$hash{reg_ex}/;

my $Variable1 = $ArrayOfMatches[$hash{Variable1}];
```

Comment: AFAIK, this doesn't work - the global match returns all matches of all parentheses in the string. Without /g, it would return ($1, $2, ...) as the OP needed.

Comment: Yeah, whoops! I knew that too. I always type g out of habit and figure out later that it's not what I want!

Answer (score 4):

Since you are already using a hash, you might as well use the builtin `%+` which maps names to matches. Thus if you changed your regexes to named matching, you could easily use `%+` to retrieve the matched parts.

```
$reg_ex = 'Variable1:\s+(?<foo>.*?)\s+\n\s+Variable2:\s+(?<bar>.*?)\s+\n';
```

After a successful match, `%+` should have the keys `foo` and `bar` and the values will correspond to what was matched.

Thus your original hash could be changed to something like this:

```
my %hash = (
    reg_ex => 'Variable1:\s+(?<foo>.*?)\s+\n\s+Variable2:\s+(?<bar>.*?)\s+\n',
    groups => [ 'foo', 'bar' ],
);
```

Comment: Named captures are the way to go if you can use Perl 5.10. There's a capture in _Learning Perl_ about them. :)

Answer (score 3):

($1, $2, $3, ...., $9)[$hash{Variable1}]

Comment: Wow! How very implicit! How very Perl ;)

Comment: yes, unlike MyFineArrayOfMatchesWhereIStoreMyMatchesYouKnow. :)